# Cannot get :hover to function

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get a mega menu to work by using hover to activate divs

i have tried it numerous ways, but i just cant get them to show on hover

here is the basic idea in jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/mXx64/5/

and here is the code

**HTML**

```
<div class="nav-container">
    <ul id="mega-menu">
        <li class="menu1">
            <a href="#">menu1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu2">
            <a href="#">menu2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu3">
            <a href="#">menu3</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu4">
            <a href="#">menu4</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="menu-area1">
    menu1
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.nav-container ul li a:hover .menu-area1 {
    display: block;
}

.menu-area1 {
    display: none;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

any help would be appreciated

*edit* please ignore the spelling mistake, i know its there, but the code doesnt work when it is fixed anyway :(

Comment: Not possible with CSS given your current HTML structure. The divs are not related to the `ul` or `li`. JS/JQ would be the answer.

Comment: Use this .nav-container ul>li>a:hover {display: block;}. It helps you.

Comment: @Jitendra Khatri That will not work for the reason stated above.

Comment: Think you need to use JavaScript here.

Comment: `.nav-container ul li a:hover .menu-area1` means that your element with a class of `menu-area1` needs to be inside the anchor that you are hovering for that style to be applied

Comment: Following @Paulie_D comment,  you can do something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mXx64/7/).

Comment: @Beterraba Acknowledged & agreed. Hence my original comment regarding the HTML structure.

Comment: "Down voting" when you don't even have a good answer yourself.

Comment: yes, i see, this is how i was originally trying to do it, but i had another issue. with your help, it is now working. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

It will not work because your ".menu-area1" is not in the anchor if you want keep this structure you need to add jQuery otherwise just do like below
working- http://jsfiddle.net/R37rr/

```
<div class="nav-container">
  <ul id="mega-menu">
    <li class="menu1"> <a href="#">menu1</a>
      <div class="menu-area1"> menu1 </div>
    </li>
    <li class="menu2"> <a href="#">menu2</a> </li>
    <li class="menu3"> <a href="#">menu3</a> </li>
    <li class="menu4"> <a href="#">menu4</a> </li>
  </ul>
</div>

.menu-area1 {
    display: none;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
.nav-container ul>li:hover .menu-area1 {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not good on JQuery but this what I got:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mXx64/12/)

```
$('li').hover(function () {
    $('.menu-area1').show();
});

$('li').hover('out',function () {
    $('.menu-area1').hide();
});
```